# Check for a theme, otherwise use value in Styled Components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Is there an easy, clean way to do this? I have a ReactJS module that I've compiled into our repository. I need this module to use default colors and styles, from itself, unless it's in a ReactJS app that is consuming the module, and that app has a theme provider set up.

I'm thinking something like

`color: ${props => props.theme ? props.theme.primaryColor : '#333'}`

I think this will work (trying it out now) but is there an easier, cleaner way of handling this with shared components? I will have a ton of these conditions across my components, feels like a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: You could use [contextAPI](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: Not sure that's what I'm looking for. I know I can use a ThemeProvider to pass a theme down to the components. But I don't want to require a ThemeProvider, I want the module to use default values when a provider is not provided

Comment: Your initial solution uses [prop drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling) however you asked for a cleaner way. contextAPI is a cleaner solution.

Comment: Styled Components uses its own context through ThemeProvider... and then my component has it nativly, not seeing where prop drilling comes in.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your entire app in a context Api
then u will provide all the components with props from the Context
so you can consume them in the entire app without passing data as a prop for all the components

- first create a context with React.createContext() in a separate file
- then store the data you need in this file .
  -create a withContext function inside the Context file

  ```
   export default function withContext(Component) {
  return function ContextComponent(props) {

    return (
      <Context.Consumer>
        {context => <Component {...props} context={context} />}
      </Context.Consumer>
    );
  }
  ```

  }

then wrap your application inside provider like this

```
import withContext from './Context'
import App from './App';

const AppWithContext = withContext(App);
     <Provider>
    <AppWithContext />
    </Provider>
```

i hope this helps you but this is the best way of passing data to all the components

Comment: Not sure that's what I'm looking for. I know I can use a `ThemeProvider` to pass a theme down to the components. But I don't want to require a `ThemeProvider`, I want the module to use default values when a provider is not provided